# Loss of color quality when saving canvas into an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, color-profile

I am implementing a cropping tool for images (using Jcrop library) that gives the possibility to upload images, choose the cropping area, and then save the image to the disk by clicking in a button.

All the logic works, except that the image saved to the disk looses it's colors tone and and few details as well.

[image]

Cropped one on the left, original on the right

My javascript of canvas drowing the following:

```
crop_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
crop_canvas.width = width;
crop_canvas.height = height;

crop_2d = crop_canvas.getContext('2d');
crop_2d.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
crop_2d.drawImage(image_target, left, top, parseInt(width), parseInt(height), 0, 0, parseInt(width), parseInt(height));

this.href = crop_canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

I'm i missing something ? Do you see something wrong ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the initial image a png? Or are you converting something else, like a jpeg, into a png?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that there is a second possible parameter for `toDataURL` which can be used to control the quality. (The default is "0.92")

Comment: The tool is supposed to accept both jpeg and png. Although for the moment i save always on png..

Comment: This is most likely due to color profiles included in the original file's metedata. Canvas exported JPEG won't keep it. Maybe some EXIF editing library can set it afterward.

Comment: Do you have any examples that i can follow ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I believe that, your development environment is Linux based system? I had this experience when I was working on image editing application on Canvas. I was developing it on Ubuntu 16.04 and I suspected this as an issue in FabricJS itself. But it was not. If I install my system on Windows or Mac it generates really nice and high quality image as I needed. Probably as we all know Linux is a best platform for application development. In this case I afraid to say that, we have to get rid of Linux. Because image rendering job is better on Windows and Mac platforms. I'm not quite sure about other Linux distributions though. I'm specifically telling about Ubuntu.

Comment: any reason for down voting?